# How do I write a finder when I have a belongs_to relationship but no underlying database column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, belongs-to

I have a Rails 5 application and I'm having a problem writing a finder.  I have a PostGres 10 database.  I want to query all the invoices that belong to a particular business.  I have these models ...

```
class Business < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :owner, :optional => true

class Owner < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :invoices, :through => :accountants
  has_one :business, :dependent => :nullify

class Accountant < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :owner, :optional => false, :inverse_of => :accountants, :touch => true
  has_many :invoices, :dependent => :nullify
```

I would like to get all Invoices given a small business, so I tried this

```
@invoices = Invoice.joins(:accountant => :owner).where(:owners => { :business_id => @business_id })
```

but this results in the below error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column owners.business_id does not exist
       LINE 1: ...owners"."id" = "accountants"."owner_id" WHERE "owners"...
                                                                    ^
       : SELECT "invoices".* FROM "invoices" INNER JOIN "accountants" ON "accountants"."id" = "invoices"."accountant_id" INNER JOIN "owners" ON "owners"."id" = "accountants"."owner_id" WHERE "owners"."business_id" = $1 ORDER BY "invoices"."created_at" DESC
```

It is not an option to add an additional database column.  Is there a way I can rewrite the above query to satisfy my models?

Comment: I'm not understanding how to apply the answer there to my question.

Comment: You must have some column as a foreign key from `owners` to `business`. By Rails convention it should be `business_id` but the error says you don't have that column.

Comment: How are tables connected in the db?

Comment: @Eyeslandic, Correct, there is a business.owner_id column  but not the other way around.  At this time, it is not an option to add or remove columns in the database.